# Printing with Selenium (Chrome): Select Pages

Tags: python, selenium

I've been using a recipe that I've cobbled together from online snippets in order to get Selenium to print the currently-visited webpage:

```
appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True
}
downloadPath=r'C:\temp'
profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':json.dumps(appState),
           'savefile.default_directory':downloadPath}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
options.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')
```

What I am struggling with now is to figure out a way to print only selected pages (e.g., only the first page). I know I can brute-force this with a PDF editor such as [How to delete pages from pdf file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574096/how-to-delete-pages-from-pdf-file-using-python) but I was curious if anyone knew of a more elegant approach here.

Thank you very much.